# Android WebView incorrectly handling newlines in preformatted text

Tags: android, html, webkit, webview

If I push this HTML into `WebView`:

```
webView.loadData("<html><body><pre>line 1\nline 2</pre></body></html>", "text/html", "utf-8");
```

it renders as (in emulator and also on device)

```
line 1line 2
```

as opposed to

```
line 1
line 2
```

as I would expect. If I save this HTML to the sdcard and open the file in the browser, it renders fine. I suppose I am doing something wrong, or this may be a bug. Any way, I want to programatically push HTML with preformatted newlines into a `WebView` and have the newlines rendered.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The string passed to `loadData` needs to be URI-escaped.

You can use `URLEncoder.encode()` to do that, but for some reason `WebView` does not decode the `'+'` back to a `' '`.  One work around is to replace all the `'+'` with `'%20'` yourself.

For example (and with the `'+'` translation):

```
try {
    webview.loadData(URLEncoder.encode("<html><body><pre>line 1\nline 2</pre></body></html>", "utf-8").replaceAll("\\+", "%20"), "text/html", "utf-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
    Log.e("webview", "", uee);
}
```

Comment: when i was passing downloaded html data from server, webview showed me "page is not available" message. this post helped me to solve my problem too

Comment: NewLines for "text/plain" - pages are still not working, even if the loaded String is Url-encoded.

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(...)
```

More info [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6965)

Comment: Simple and working! Example call: `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);`

Answer (score 4):

Also you can use

```
chapterWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/NTImages/", message.replaceAll("\\n", "<br/>") , "text/html", "utf-8", "utf-8");
```