# How to load html string in a webview?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

i have a html string containing this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">
    <html>
      <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
      <meta name="spanish press" content="spain, spanish newspaper, news,economy,politics,sports">  
      <title></title>
      </head>
      <body id="body">  
<!-- The following code will render a clickable image ad in the page -->
        <script src="http://www.myscript.com/a"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

I need to show that website into a webview in android.

I tryed with all this:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, txt, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("x-data://base", txt, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);      
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("notreal/", txt, "text/htm", "utf-8",null);
```

Also i tryed removing DOCTYPE tag:

`txt=txt.replace("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">", "");`

No one of those have work. I just achieved to show the string into the webview (the html code), but not the website that must be created with that html code.

What is wrong?

Comment: did you try `loadData` ?

Comment: you can put this html string to file res/values/strings.xml and create item for example `<string name="website">your html here</string>` and then load it by `Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.website))`, please check it if you have some time, because I would like to know if it works too ;)

Comment: (what do you need base url for, anyway ?)

Comment: @Lumma : Html.fromHtml is not meant for use with webView. It returns a Spanned that for use with TextViews.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

To load your data in WebView. Call loadData() method of WebView

```
wv.loadData(yourData, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

You can check this example

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

[Edit 1]

You should add -- \  -- before -- " --   for example -->   **name=\"spanish press\"**

below string worked for me

```
String webData =  "<!DOCTYPE html><head> <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" " +
"content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"> <html><head><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=windows-1250\">"+
 "<meta name=\"spanish press\" content=\"spain, spanish newspaper, news,economy,politics,sports\"><title></title></head><body id=\"body\">"+
"<script src=\"http://www.myscript.com/a\"></script>şlkasşldkasşdksaşdkaşskdşk</body></html>";
```

Comment: don't works, simply shows a empty white view with no content.

Comment: For correct UTF-8 you should use `webView.loadData(data, "text/html; charset=UTF-8;", null);` as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/9312031

Comment: we should use `loadDataWithBaseURL` instead because `loadData` don't handle next line (`\n`) https://stackoverflow.com/q/5027084/5381331

Comment: data = "<iframe...</iframe>" doesn't work, get blank view

Comment: Before using loadData please look at this https://goyalnitesh.medium.com/how-to-load-an-html-string-in-a-webview-in-googles-recommended-way-2cd6e8788e3

Answer (score 18):

You also can try out this

```
   final WebView webView = new WebView(this);
            webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, content, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Answer (score 12):

read from assets html file

```
ViewGroup webGroup;
  String content = readContent("content/ganji.html");

        final WebView webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, content, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

        webGroup.addView(webView);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirement and I have done this in the following way. You also can try this out.

Use loadData method

```
web.loadData("""
    <p style='text-align:center'>
        <img class='aligncenter size-full wp-image-1607' title='' src="+movImage+" alt='' width='240px' height='180px' />
    </p>
    <p>
        <center>
            <U>
                <H2>"+movName+"("+movYear+")</H2>
            </U>
        </center>
    </p>
    <p><strong>Director : </strong>"+movDirector+"</p>
    <p><strong>Producer : </strong>"+movProducer+"</p>
    <p><strong>Character : </strong>"+movActedAs+"</p>
    <p><strong>Summary : </strong>"+movAnecdotes+"</p>
    <p><strong>Synopsis : </strong>"+movSynopsis+"</p>
    """,
   "text/html",
   "UTF-8"
);
```

movDirector movProducer like all are my string variable.

In short I retain custom styling for my URL.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for something in JetpackCompose this can help you:

```
@Composable 
fun HtmlTextVisualizerComponent(textFromData: String) {
val mimeType = "text/html"
val encoding = "UTF-8"

LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(
            start = 24.dp,
            end = 24.dp,
            top = 16.dp,
            bottom = 24.dp,
        ),
) {
    items(1) {
        val state = rememberWebViewState(
            url = "data:$mimeType;$encoding,$textFromData",
        )
        val navigator = rememberWebViewNavigator()
        WebView(
            state = state,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            navigator = navigator,
            onCreated = {
                it.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
            },
        )
    }
  }
}
```

sure don't forget to add the dependency in your gradle:

```
 implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-webview:0.30.1"
```