# Run script in WebBrowser Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone

I have following issue: I retrieved ad as script

```
<script>...</script>
```

and script needs to use webiste in order to correctly display ad. I tried to download website html, insert my script and run but the whole website kick off loading, my goal was to run only a script.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Windows Phone 8 - you can use [InvokeScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc491132(v=vs.110).aspx) method (WebBrowser).
If you use Windows Phone 8.1 - you can use [InvokeScriptAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync.aspx) methos (WebView)

Comment: The issue is that I have no function inside that could be called.

Comment: Do you have script which you want to run in webbrowser?

Comment: Yeah, but that script needs to use another scipts from webiste. It has "<script src="/folder..."/>" but that folder can only be accessed on website so needs a connection as if it was "website_address/folder".

Comment: Similar to this, I need to run script with base uri. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816464/how-to-load-html-string-in-a-webview

Comment: You can invoke your scrip after webniew loaded event firing.
Or you can load all html from your url ans after edit it and after editing - load it to wibView.