# Load data with base uri Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone

Is in windows phone equivalent of IOS method called loadHTMLString:baseURL or android loadDatawithBaseUrl ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816464/how-to-load-html-string-in-a-webview)). I want to run script on website and that is why I need this base url to be invoked.

Comment: Are you trying to invoke a RESTful web service?

Answer (score -1):

By looking at the reference link, I think what you are trying to achieve is a `web browser` control on Windows Phone to display a remote HTML page on the app page.

- LOAD FROM REMOTE URL:

**Step 1: Load WebBrowser control on your app page from the Toolbox on page.xaml**

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" Grid.Row="1">
    <phone:WebBrowser HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="webBrowser1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="800" Width="470" />
</Grid>
```

**Step 2: Write C# code (you can even use VB.NET) on page.xaml.cs**

```
webBrowser1.Source = new Uri("http://www.foo.com", UriKind.Absolute);
```

- LOAD FROM LOCAL HTML STRING

Here Step 1 remains the same, just to load an HTML code locally:

**Step 2: C# Code on page.xaml.cs**

```
String htmlContent = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=windows-1250\">
  <meta name=\"spanish press\" content=\"spain, spanish newspaper, news,economy,politics,sports\">  
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body id=\"body\">  
  <!-- The following code will render a clickable image ad in the page -->
    <script src=\"http://www.myscript.com/a\"></script>
  </body>
</html>";

webBrowser1.NavigateToString(htmlContent); //This renders the HTML string defined above in the webview.
```

**EDIT:** Also, if you want to allow scripts to execute in the webview, set `IsScriptEnabled` property of the webbrowser control to `true`.

```
webBrowser1.IsScriptEnabled = true;
```

Comment: I have some script from website X. In order to run those script I need to retrieve another scripts, styles etc. from that website so my aim was to run website (to be able to use those required elements) and run that script.

Comment: @Maximus: your description seems vague. Can you explain with some pseudo. I will get a better idea to help you :)

Comment: I've been trying to do this same thing, and it doesn't appear to be possible.  There is a BaseUrl property, but it is read only.

Comment: Okay, so here is (sort of) how we did this: You can add a <base> html tag to the file, and it will look for resources in that location.  For us, it looked like <base href=\"ms-appx-web:///Assets/\">.  This let us load local resources.  However, we ran into another problem, as NavigateToStream does not allow scripts to be run.