# How to populate webview in android with plain text from database and be able to handle newline characters

Tags: javascript, android, webview, zooming, scrollview

I am new to java and android development
I am working on an application which contains simple GUI for accessing and reading fundamental programs in C and Java for students.

**I am trying to populate a webview with a text file(a C-program in this case) which is pre-loaded in a certain column of my database.**

I decided against using a scrollview because simultaneously scrolling and zooming is very difficult to implement. Zooming requires making custom implementations which were difficult for me to understand.

Thus I decided to use webview since it is readily scrollable and requires just 1 line of code to implement zooming of text.

**I have 2 problems:**

**1) the webview is unable to handle newline using my current implementation.i.e it tries to display all the text on the same line instead of going to the next line**

**2) it does not display "stdio.h","stdlib.h",etc....basically all words with .h extension   which is part of almost all C programs.It is essential to display these.**

**I have tried the following 2 implementations(perhaps incorrectly):**

**1)  loadData** (String data, String mimeType, String encoding)

**2)  loadDataWithBaseURL** (String baseUrl, String data, String mimeType, String encoding, String historyUrl)

**My Code is as follows:**

```
package com.example.uopengineering;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class viewProgramActivity<x> extends Activity {

    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    ExternalDbOpenHelper dbOpenHelper;

    private WebView webView;
    private static final String DB_NAME = "umangdb.db";
    private String rowid;
    private String programtext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewprogram);


        dbOpenHelper = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(this, DB_NAME);
        database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();

        Intent intent=getIntent();
        rowid=intent.getStringExtra("myextra");

        String query="select * from engg_table where _id="+rowid;
        Cursor myCursor = database.rawQuery(query,null);
        myCursor.moveToFirst();

        programtext=myCursor.getString(4);
        myCursor.close();

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        //webView.loadData(programtext, "text/html", "UTF-8");
        try {
            webView.loadData(URLEncoder.encode(programtext,"utf-8").replaceAll("\\+"," "), "text/html", "utf-8");
            //webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, programtext, null, query, null);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The corresponding XML file(for layout puposes) is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines = "22"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"
         />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I went through other forums having similar questions but was unable to find suitable solutions.
One of them suggested **using javascript to work around this problem**.
All I know about javascripts is doing validations in web application forms for my college project.Is this possible ?? If so,how do you suggest I go about learning javascript and how exactly am I supposed to implement it.

Also,**How does replaceAll("\+"," ")** work ?How exactly is it removing undesired characters ??Also I'm not very familiar with character encoding standards

Comment: You're trying to render source code as HTML? You'll need to process it to HTML then, e.g. replace `<` with `&lt;`, `>` with `&gt;`, `&` with `&amp;`, linefeeds with `<br/>` and so on. Or to get more quickly started, pass the `WebView` content-type `text/plain` so it won't get interpreted as HTML.

Comment: changing content type to text/plain worked for me !! The solution was simple and elegant.                                        Thanks @laalto

Answer (score 3):

Just changing the content type to "text/plain" did not work for me in Android 4.4. All the content was still in one line.
What worked though is the accepted answer in this Stack Overflow question:

[Android WebView incorrectly handling newlines in preformatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027084/android-webview-incorrectly-handling-newlines-in-preformatted-text)